# navigate lines with alphabets

Tags: neovim, line-numbers

I am using Programmer Dvorak layout.
So typing numbers for navigation is not easy.
Can I instead navigate with alphabetical characters showing up in place of relative numbers?
Any other ideas?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KB_Programmer_Dvorak.svg

Comment: Anything useful here https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Using_Vim_with_the_Dvorak_keyboard_layout ? Also, googling "vim dvorak" reveals a slew of  articles about using dvorak style keyboards with Vim. Gotta be something you can use there, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like the [vim-easyoperator-line](https://github.com/haya14busa/vim-easyoperator-line) plug-in, which allow you to create a mapping that will highlight each line with an alphabetic or punctuation character and have you press it to move to that line. Sounds like what you described...

This plug-in was spawned from [vim-easymotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion) which does something similar, but primarily for motions of the kind `f{char}` or searches using `/`, but you might find you actually like the full set of motions provided by vim-easymotion and decide to go with that one.

Comment: By the way, EasyMotion does it from the box. See <Leader>j in docs. Default mapping will be double leader + j. Same for k.